# Deploying ClickOnce windows forms application on windows server for test user

Tags: winforms, clickonce

NOTE: I am not a server administrator, I'm simply a programmer.

I have an application which uses ClickOnce and I was wondering what is the best way to deploy the application on a Windows server for specific groups?

Anyone got any experience with this?

Thanks and best regards
Helios

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The answer for me, is to create a shared folder on the server, use the UNC path to publish directly to the server and then only once, install the software, once I publish again, it will show as an update.